# Output identical fields names of two LEFT JOIN tables Sql

Tags: sql, left-join

I have two tables, with about 20 columns each

**users**:

```
id_user   user ..... status token
----------------------------------
   2      A             0   XdAQ
```

**posts**:

```
id_user  post .....  status   token
-------------------------------------
   3     hi             1     sDyTMl
```

Query:

```
SELECT u.*,p.*
FROM posts as p
LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id_user = p.id_user
WHERE p.id_post = 3 
LIMIT 1
```

So in Php, it could be retrieved any value

```
 ....
 $status=$a['status'];
 $token=$a['token'];
```

I want to return all the fields of each table to make the post content, the problem is that there is conflict among those identical column names in each table. there are more than 20 columns in each in my real tables, so writing the column names with aliases I think is not the way to go. Is there a way to  alias only those identical columns in conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really *should* list the specific columns that you want.  This is the safest way to retrieve values from the table.

If the only column that is in common is the one used for the `join`, you can use the `USING` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
     users as u 
     USING (id_user)
WHERE p.id_post = 3
LIMIT 1;
```

The `USING` clause is ANSI standard, but not all databases support it.  When you use it, only one version of `id_post` is in the columns returned by the `SELECT *`.  In a `LEFT JOIN`, it is the version with a value.

If you have other columns with the same name, you need to use column aliases.  One short-cut is to take all columns from one table and name the columns in the other:

```
SELECT u.*, p.col1 as p_col1, . . .
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
     users as u 
     USING (id_user)
WHERE p.id_post = 3
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Ok, I do undertstand. I think I'll need to name the columns of the second table one by one... thank you !

Comment: hey I have this new question, I would be glad if you can check it, thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/48999783/9369685